# dynamic transportation value in cart app laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, shopping-cart

I want to get the transportation cost from the database in the card.php but now its write statically 25000 .this cost must be dynamic that owner of site can be change it.

[image]

in photo transportation write staticly
but I want call in from database and is dynamic

```
public function __construct($oldCart)

{
    if($oldCart){
        $this->items = $oldCart->items;
        $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
        $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
        $this->totalPurePrice = $oldCart->totalPurePrice;
        $this->totalDiscountPrice = $oldCart->totalDiscountPrice;
        $this->transportation = $oldCart->transportation;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Do this after the code that you put the photo above.you don't need `__construct`. you should have getter and setter like this:

```
public function setTransportation($value)
    {
        $this->transportation= $value;
    }

    public function getTransportation()
    {
        return $this->transportation;
    }
```

and in another method set a value (example : 5) you can give it from database:

```
$this->setTransportation(5);
```

Then get it this way:

```
$myTransportation=$this->getTransportation();
```